# TProgressBar with decimal value

Tags: delphi, vcl

Is it possible fill progress bar with decimal value?

Any solution?

Comment: Define what you mean by decimal please. Do you mean not an integer?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan For example  current_value  from database is 10,57  max value is  88.40. How put this value in progress bar?

Comment: @Pointer: Indeed, then you only need to multiply all your values with 100 and then round them, as hinted in my answer. Or you could normalize and use a 0..100 scale. For example, your progress is 10.57 / 88.40 = 0.11957... Multiplying with 100 yields 11.957..., which is the percentage. You can round that to obtain 12 as an integer (with max = 100).

Comment: Convert the value into a percentage, and round, as @Andreas says. Do you know how to calculate percentages?. Do note though that your use of the word "decimal" is incorrect. Decimal is base 10, in the way that binary is base 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A progress bar's progress is always specified using integers. However, you can achieve essentially any (reasonable) precision you need using integers.

For example, you could set `Min` to `0` and `Max` to `1000000` and set `Position` to `63267` to get the same result as if the range had been floating-point values from `0` to `1` and the position had been `0.063267`.

Typically, that precision is too high, though. More likely you would use integral percent values. Set `Min` to `0` and `Max` to `100` and let `Position` be `32` to get `32` percent (that is, `0.32` in decimal).

Of course, in many applications the process has a natural integral range, and if so, you'd use that. For example, if you are to copy `N` files, you set `Min` to `0` and `Max` to `N` and `Position` to the number of files copied so far.